# Where should layout functions live in an Angular app?

Tags: angularjs, organization

In the absence of proper CSS3 support, I have a javascript function that keeps our layout looking nice.

```
var handleWindowResize = function() {
    // Code omitted because i don't think it's relevant
};
```

It needs to be invoked in the following scenarios

- Window load
- Window resize
- Whenever [$viewContentLoaded](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angView#Events) is fired

Where is the best place to put this sort of code in an AngularJS app?

Comment: I usually put a 'MasterController' on body tag and use it to handle all global stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want to do this in a controller.  Controllers should not reference the DOM.  Instead, you want to create a directive to do this.  Create a directive that describes our behavior, like "maintain-layout" and put your behavior in that directive.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. Would I then bind that directive to the body tag like `<body maintain-layout>` or something?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what you should do!